# How to run/deploy devilbox (Docker image) docker-compose on GCP without a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, google-cloud-platform

Devilbox comes with a docker-compose file to run a docker container:
https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox

However, on the GCP Kubernetes Engine it is only possible to start up a new container via a Dockerfile. I searched for a translation/conversion tool of the docker-compose file to a Dockerfile. I could not find an easy way and also read that this is not the go to approach. Is there a way to let it run in the Kubernetes Engine or do I have to create a manual instance, upload and run the code manually?
Any other approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `docker-compose` is is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications. (https://docs.docker.com/compose/).
Dockerfile is single-container, if you want to run multi-containers on GKE you should convert docker-compose to kubernetes deployment.

You can manually convert or use http://kompose.io/ to convert automatically.